# How do I bold a String that I'm passing in through a message service?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, service, components

My service looks as follows:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class MessageService {
  messages: string[] = [];

  add(message: string) {
    this.messages.push(message);
  }

  clear() {
    this.messages = [];
  }
}
```

The HTML for the associated component looks like this:

```
<div>
    <h4>Status Messages:</h4>
    <div *ngFor='let message of messageService.messages'> {{message}} </div>
  </div>
```

I normally call it in other components like this:

```
this.messageService.add('Completed all current actions.')
```

Say I wanted to just bold the word "Completed". Any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: There's no one answer to this, because it would depend a lot on how you want to implement it. If you want to allow HTML markup in your messages, you'd have to adapt whatever code you're using to display `this.messages` in `MessageService`. But once you did that, `this.messageService.add('<b>Completed</b> all current actions.')`.

Comment: I've tried doing this.messageService.add('<b>Completed</b> all current actions.') and it just displays "<b>" rather than adding any styling because I haven't altered my MessageService code. Do you have any ideas on how to alter the MessageService? I apologize, I'm relatively new to Front-End Development. @kshetline

Comment: If you're ultimately displaying the messages using {{...}} notation, that will undo HTML markup and turn it into plain text. If, however, you use the `[innerHTML]` attribute, you can assign markup and have the markup work. There's stuff about "sanitizing" HTML that comes up, however, and the slight chance of having text that you don't mean to have treated as markup treated that way anyway, so you'll have to investigate those subjects before proceeding -- it's a bit much to fully describe here. (I see now you've already got a more complete answer using `outerHTML` instead.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to changed your data model.

You can define Message, which represents single sentence with array of words, which need to be highlighted.

```js
export interface Message {
    text: string;
    wordsToHighlight: string[];
}
```

Then during iteration over the messages array, create html string and use HTML element's innerHTML or outerHTML property to render it.
Pay attention on `getHighlightedText` method below.

Your component may look like this:

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'app-demo',
    template: `
        <div *ngFor="let message of messages" [outerHTML]="getHighlightedText(message)"></div>
    `
})
export class DemoComponent implements OnInit {

    messages: Message[];

    constructor(private readonly messageService: MessageService) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.messages = this.messageService.messages;
        this.messageService.add({ text: 'Completed all current actions', wordsToHighlight: ['all', 'actions'] })
    }

    getHighlightedText(message: Message): string {
        const words = message.text.split(' ');

        return words.map((word) => {
            const highlight = message.wordsToHighlight.some((wordToHighlight) => word.toLowerCase() === wordToHighlight.toLowerCase());

            if (highlight) {
                return `<b>${word}</b>`;
            } else {
                return word;
            }
        }).join(' ');
    }
}
```

Message service:

```js
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class MessageService {
    messages: Message[] = [];

    add(message: Message) {
        this.messages.push(message);
    }

    clear() {
        this.messages = [];
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably a dumb question, but it used to display with each "Completed all current actions." message on a new line (because I call displayService.add() a few times). How would you make it still do this (preferably without just adding \n or something)?

Comment: @JCrew0 change `outerHTML` to `innerHTML`.